# How to compile Swift code targeting the latest SDKs using Xcode 7 and 8?

Tags: xcode, swift, foundation

The nullability of some methods on the NSURL API changed between iOS 9 and 10.

For example, [iOS 10 returns an optional](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1413953-urlbyappendingpathcomponent) for the `URLByAppendingPathComponent` function but [iOS 9 does not](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:). Using `#available` isn't going to work because it is not a compile time check.

```
    let appSupportURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
    let folder: NSURL
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        folder = appSupportURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Folder", isDirectory: true)!
    } else {
        folder = appSupportURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Folder", isDirectory: true)
    }
```

How can I build the Swift code in my app with both Xcode 7 or Xcode 8 while still targeting the latest iOS SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At WWDC 2016, Ewa Matejska [presented the following technique](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/402/?time=2360):

```
#if swift(>=2.3)
// code that builds against iOS 10 SDK.
#else
// code that builds against iOS 9 SDK.
#endif
```

This technique is also [documented on the Swift blog](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/).